# How I Can Show More Table In Datagridview C#

Tags: c#, mysql

can i show two table or more in one datagridview using c# and mysql sorting by date ?

### for ex:

---

### | table1.salesNo | table1.salesMoney | table1.date1 |

### | table2.purchNo | table2.purchMoney | table2.date2 |

### | table2.purchNo | table2.purchMoney | table2.date3 |

### | table1.salesNo | table1.salesMoney | table1.date4 |

### | table1.salesNo | table1.salesMoney | table1.date5 |

---

i used this code but no data appear

```
 private MySqlDataAdapter salesinvoices, purchasesinvoices;
        private DataSet jedataset;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          const string SELECT_salesinvoices = "SELECT * FROM sales_invoices";
          const string SELECT_purchasesinvoices = "SELECT * FROM purchase_invoices";



          // Compose the connection string.
          string connect_string = Publics.je_Coonn;

          // Create a DataAdapter to load the Addresses table.
          salesinvoices = new MySqlDataAdapter(SELECT_salesinvoices,
              connect_string);

          // Create a DataAdapter to load the Addresses table.
          purchasesinvoices = new MySqlDataAdapter(SELECT_purchasesinvoices,
              connect_string);

          // Create and fill the DataSet.
          jedataset = new DataSet("je_coronasalesdbDataSet");
          salesinvoices.Fill(jedataset, "sales_invoices");
          purchasesinvoices.Fill(jedataset, "purchase_invoices");

          // Bind the DataGrid to the DataSet.
          dataGridView1.DataSource = jedataset;
      }
```

thanks

Comment: Looks like you need `dataGridView1.DataBind();` after setting `DataSource`.

Comment: thanks,  i tried that but this error appear System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type

Comment: `DataBind()` does not take any arguments. Try adding the line exactly as I've entered it in the previous comment.

Comment: i did that dataGridView1.DataBind(); exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I know **DataBind()** works with Web Forms only. Try just binding with the property **.DataSource**. Just in case still don't work try **.Refresh()**

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = jedataset;
dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

Edit: If you STILL see no data add:

```
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true
```

(I don't know if you already added the columns)

Edit 2: Found this code [**here**](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/838741/How-do-I-bind-two-DataTables-to-one-DataGridView-w), I don't tested it, but you can adapt it and try if works:

```
private static void DemonstrateMergeTable()
{
    DataTable table1 = new DataTable("Items");

    // Add columns
    DataColumn column1 = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
    DataColumn column2 = new DataColumn("item", typeof(System.Int32));
    table1.Columns.Add(column1);
    table1.Columns.Add(column2);

    // Set the primary key column.
    table1.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { column1 };



    // Add some rows.
    DataRow row;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        row = table1.NewRow();
        row["id"] = i;
        row["item"] = i;
        table1.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    // Accept changes.
    table1.AcceptChanges();
    PrintValues(table1, "Original values");

    // Create a second DataTable identical to the first.
    DataTable table2 = table1.Clone();

    // Add three rows. Note that the id column can't be the  
    // same as existing rows in the original table.
    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 14;
    row["item"] = 774;
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 12;
    row["item"] = 555;
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    row = table2.NewRow();
    row["id"] = 13;
    row["item"] = 665;
    table2.Rows.Add(row);

    // Merge table2 into the table1.
    Console.WriteLine("Merging");
    table1.Merge(table2);
    PrintValues(table1, "Merged With table1");

}
```

Comment: ,, no data appear  ,,, dataGridView1 don't have any columns

Comment: Okay, try this: dataGridView1.DataSource = jedataset.Tables[0]; @SunEye

Comment: sales_invoices only appear

Comment: That's because a DataSet is a collection of DataTables, and you have 2 tables (0 and 1). 0 = sales, 1 = purchases. The thing that you are trying to do is kinda complex and not recommendable because DataGridView is designed for handling only one data source. As far I know is imposible to combine two DataTable into one. What you **CAN DO** is create a create a **Custom Object** that contains all purchases fields and all sales fields, parse them to the **Custom Object type** and then list all to finally bind the **Custom Object List** with the dataGridView. You'll deal with 1 datasource @SunEye

Comment: The name 'PrintValues' does not exist in the current context , how i can create a Custom Object that contains all purchases fields and all sales fields and how i can bind the two table1 and table 2 with datagridview